# Use of an entity as a parameter in a Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, methods, entity

Using MVC, when I register, I want to be able to create a couple of records in seperate tables (an account and a user)

I could set up different methods for each create but as I like to learn, I thought I'd try to use Generics in just one method. This may or not be appropriate so please point out if it isn't.

So the register method has in it the following code:

```
sp_Account spAccount = new sp_Account();
// stripped out code assignations
Create(spAccount);
sp_User spUser = new sp_User();
// stripped out code assignations
Create(spUser);
```

And after Googling for a while, I have (rightly or wrongly) set the Create method as follows:

```
protected ActionResult Create<T>(T modelOf)
        {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
            Type t = modelOf.GetType();

            switch(t.Name)
              {
              case "sp_Account":
                 sp_Account spAccount = new sp_Account();
                 spAccount = ??????????;
                 db.sp_Account.Add(spAccount );

                 return View(spAccount);
                 break;
              case "sp_User":
                sp_User spUser = new sp_User();
                spUser = ??????????;
                db.sp_User.Add(spUser);

                return View(spUser);
                break;
              }
            db.SaveChanges();
          }

          return View(**********);
        }
```

> 2 questions please:
>
> 1. ?????????? - How do I assign the generic modelOf to a particular entity
> 2. ********** - How do I return the generic modelOf as a model for the View

New to this so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.
And thanks in advance for those who help.

**UPDATE**
I would like to open up this "Create" method to ANY entity I have.

Comment: I would do this differently.  First separate concerns, don't mix Controller functions with database functions.  2nd I would not use Generic for inbound get/post request, rather I would create a strong type container that can handle the two types no problem.  It's the container that decides the type and NOT the MVC Binding engine.

Comment: @John Apologies as I didn't make this clear in the original post but I'd like to open up thie Create method to any entity I have. Hence I thought I could use a generic entity being passed into the method and then handle it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further Googling finally managed to join all the info to work out a solution.

My working Create method now looks like this:

```
protected void Create<TEntity>(TEntity modelOf) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        db.Set<TEntity>().Add(modelOf);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to see you found a nice example.  My only question now is how does the view bind to something it may not know?  Dynamic field display?

Comment: @John The Create method is called from within the Register method so doesn't need to return a view. Register handles that. So amended the solution to the proper void action. Thanks